# How to remove file extension in hyperlink, in this specific situation?

Tags: php, html

There is a php gallery code that creates a gallery from a directory of images.

When clicking on the image it has a hyperlink to show a larger preview of the image.  I have a need where I want to change the hyperlink to direct to a different page on my website, which I am able to, however it retains the file extension in the folder, example myimage.png

In order for my link to work properly the .png needs to be removed from the myimage

Example:  When defining my link it is like this:

```
mysitepage.html?myiframe=myothersitepage.html%3Fmyimage
```

Therefore in the code I define this portion of my link as:

```
**$link_page** = '../mysitepage.html?myiframe=myothersitepage.html%3F';
```

in the code below the image name is is defined as $k

*so in the original code I changed the line:*

```
$imgl .= "< div class=\"img_thumb\" >< a href=\"$k\">
```

*to read:*

```
$imgl .= "< div class=\"img_thumb\" >< a href=\"**$link_page**$k\">
```

this returns the link: `mysitepage.html?myiframe=myothersitepage.html%3Fmyimage.png`

Again, I cannot figure out how to get rid of the .png in that link.

Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace the extension with empty string in PHP before using it:

```
$k = str_ireplace('.png', '', $k);
```

If you want to do it client-side, here's a jQuery solution:

```
$(function() {
    $('.img_thumb a').each(function() {
        var link = $(this).attr('href').replace(/\.png$/i, '');
        $(this).attr('href', link);
    });
});
```

If you want to replace all extensions:

```
$k = preg_replace('/\.[a-z]+$/i', '', $k);
```

And jQuery:

```
$(function() {
    $('.img_thumb a').each(function() {
        var link = $(this).attr('href').replace(/\.[a-z]+$/i, '');
        $(this).attr('href', link);
    });
});
```

If you are using $k in multiple places (which you did not mention earlier), you can also perform the replace inline:

```
imgl .= "<div class=\"img_thumb\">
    <a href=\"$link_page".str_ireplace('.png', '', $k)."\">
        <img src=\"gallery.php?thumb=$k\" alt=\"$alt\" title=\"$alt\" />
    </a>
</div>";
```

Comment: And if you need other extensions removed: `$k = str_replace(array('.png','.jpg','.gif'), '', $k);`

Comment: Where would this be defined if $k is defined previously?  Can you provide where it would be placed?thanks for the reply.

Comment: I added it there, and now the link works, but the image src $k gallery preview is broken.

Comment: sorry, yes, it defines the image link and the preview:  imgl .= "<div class=\"img_thumb\"><a href=\"$link_page$k\"><img src=\"gallery.php?thumb=$k\" alt=\"$alt\" title=\"$alt\" />

Answer (score 0):

Instead of appending `$k` append `$k` with '.png' removed using `str_replace()`

```
$imgl .= "< div class=\"img_thumb\" >< a href=\"**$link_page**" . str_replace('.png', '', $k) . "\">";
```